# Optimized way of negation of values in solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am trying to search the results for the negation of particular id in solr. It have found that this can be done in two ways:

(1) fq=userid:(-750376)
(2) fq=-userid:750376

Both are working fine and both are giving correct results. But I can one tell me which is the better way of either two. Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what query the `fq` parameter's value is parsed into by turning on debugQuery (add the parameter `debug=true`). Then, in the Solr response, there should be an entry "parsed_filter_queries" under "debug", and the entry should show the string representation of the parsed filter query (or queries) being used.

In your case, both forms of `fq` should be parsed into the same query, i.e. a boolean query with a single clause stating that the term `userid:750376` must not occur. Therefore, which form you use does not matter, at least in terms of correctness or performance.

Answer (score 0):

For us the query looks little different. But for Solr, both are same.

First, Solr parse the query provided by you. Then search for the result. In your case, for both the queries Solr's "**parsed_filter_queries**" is `fq=-userid:750376` only.

1. fq=userid:(-750376)
2. fq=-userid:750376

You can check this by enabling **debugQuery** from Admin window. You can also pass `debugQuery=true` with query. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Kai Chan & buddy86. It worked for me. I got the point.